# What made the old versions of the bitcoin wallet insecure?

Tags: wallet

According to the downloads for the Bitcoin client, versions older than ~0.3.0 were "insecure".  Since they are not available for download (and the lack of security is the given reason) no one can learn from them or verify the reason.

The question I have is, 1, does anyone have a copy of the original wallets and or their source code for download and, 2, does anyone know what made them insecure?

Answer (score 2):

The source code for old versions is available in the [Bitcoin-Qt Git repository](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin). Click on the "branch: master" button and then select "Tags", and you can go all the way back to v0.1.5.

Comment: Thank you, didn't realize it was under tags.  Still wondering what made them "insecure".

Comment: @Mine For one thing, you can create transactions that create billions of Bitcoins, and that client will accept them without complaint.